# POST request video - iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, video, youtube-api, http-post

I have an iOS Application which send over a video file via a POST request to YouTube (Authorised over OAuth 2.0). However, it I get the error response back saying "Not found (404)".

I think the issue is that I need to add a JSON parameter body (like this one:https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#resource), but I;m not too sure.

I have been following the instructions on this Google Dev Page: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert#examples

Here is my code:

```
NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoUrl];
        NSString *yt_upload = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos&access_token=%@", token_youtube];
        NSString *urlString = yt_upload;

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

        NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
        NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
        [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

        NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\".mov\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:videoData]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [request setHTTPBody:body];

        NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
        NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"%@", response);
        NSLog(@"%@", returnString);
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
```

Does anyone know whats wrong? Why doesn't the video upload properly?

Thanks for your time, Dan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure this out in the end. The main issue is that you have to deal with two request/responses from the YouTube server. In the first request, you set up the OAuth headers and the parameters as well as a JSON body which contains your video information. This request if sent properly will then send you back a response with an upload URL. You then need to make another request to the upload URL with the actual video file. And then it will work.